# Не полностью работает jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В скрипте **не выполняется команда removeClass**, addClass работает. **Нужно чтоб скрипт add и remove были именно по отдельности**, через if и else мне в моей ситуации не подходит

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  }; 
         });
   $(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  } ;
    });
    
});
```

```css
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.active {
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть через else/else if в одном слушателе, вот так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Можно чуть короче записать:

    `$(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
        $(this)[$(this).hasClass('active') ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('active');
    });`

Или вообще: `$(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});`

Comment: а как можно по отдельности? я же писал,  что такой способ мне не подходит

Comment: -----все, спасибо, подогнал под этот код------